# Distinct on one column with additional criteria to select non-unique rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, unique

Okay, I know a lot of variations on this question have been asked, but here I go.

I'm starting with this query.

```
SELECT lprArchived, lprReportId, lprOwner
FROM ReportIndex
WHERE lprArchived = 1
```

In most cases, each row returned will have a unique value in the `lprReportId` column. However, for cases where multiple rows have the same value in `lprReportId`, I only want one row.

So which one? I would prefer the row where `lprOwner = 'ABCD'`.

Is it possible to write a query that would return unique rows and, in cases where rows were not unique, give me the one that has `lprOwner = 'ABCD'`?

*Note: I believe that only one row will match `lprOwner = 'ABCD'` for a given `lprReportId`, but if for some reason there was more than one, I'd still only want one row returned.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
It will take one record per `lprReportId` and in cases where there are multiple entries with the same `lprReportId`, it will prioritise ones that have an `lprOwner` = 'ABCD'

```
SELECT t.Archived, t.ReportID, t.[Owner]
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY lprReportId ORDER BY lprReportId, CASE WHEN lprOwner = 'ABCD' THEN 1 ELSE 10 END ) AS RowNum,
        lprArchived AS Archived,
        lprReportId AS ReportID,
        lprOwner AS [Owner]

    FROM 
        ReportIndex

    WHERE
        lprArchived = 1
) t
WHERE t.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: Added some more info on what the solution is doing. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1
        lprArchived, 
        lprReportId, 
        lprOwner
    from ReportIndex
    where 
        lprArchived = 1
    order by case when lprOwner = 'ABCD' then 0 else 1 end asc
```

This will take all matches, order them with 'ABCD' at the top, and then take the first row.  If you have any other criteria for selecting rows, you could add it to the end of the order by clause (most recent, for example).

Comment: This only returns one row total. But I want one row for each distinct value in `lprReportId`.